# Managed package and triggers

Tags: apex, trigger, managed-package, install

I have a managed package with a trigger on lead object. I added a trigger handler class and a trigger object. I wanted to know how does the trigger integrate with local triggers on package installation. For eg.
Following classes are present in :

Managed package:

```
 LeadTrigger.trigger
 LeadTriggerHandler.cls
```

Subscriber org :

```
 LeadTrigger_local.trigger
```

How would the triggers work in conjunction with local triggers? Do I need to make modifications after the package is installed to add my trigger handler to the local trigger class (in this case - LeadTrigger_local.trigger) . I'm unsure how this works. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If by "in conjunction with local triggers" you mean which fires first? then the answer is the order of execution is not guaranteed. so lets say you have a trigger on lead in managed package and a custom trigger on lead both on Insert. any trigger can fire first

Comment: They are independent of each other

Answer (score 1):

Well, in a nutshell, as some people stated in the comments, the order of execution of the triggers is not guaranteed. Therefor, it's just as if you create two lead triggers in your org and then make a DML - Both will execute, but you will never know which first in advance.

You can find information regarding the order of execution in the docs, [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm).

Your best bet is to make the login within the trigger as solid as possible so that it won't break regardless of what other triggers in the org do. Take into account recursion scenarios, etc.